# how to get permission to replace the utilman.exe

Tags: vbscript

I would like to get the permission to replace or rename the `utilman.exe`. The script below is not working.

```
Dim strFolder, strUser, strDomain
strFolder = "c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run("takeown /A /f" & Chr(34) & strFolder & chr(34)),1,True
objShell.Run("icacls chr(34) & strFodler &  chr(34) /grant administrator:F"),1,True
Wscript.quit
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `icacls` commandline as a single string when you apparently want it to contain the value of the variable `strFolder` in double quotes. You must use string concatenation for this to work in VBScript. Also, you may want to put a space after the parameter `/f` of `takeown` and remove the parentheses around the commands.

Change this:

```
objShell.Run("takeown /A /f" & Chr(34) & strFolder & chr(34)),1,True
objShell.Run("icacls chr(34) & strFodler &  chr(34) /grant administrator:F"),1,True
```

into this:

```
objShell.Run "takeown /A /f " & Chr(34) & strFolder & chr(34), 1, True
objShell.Run "icacls " & chr(34) & strFolder &  chr(34) & " /grant administrator:F", 1, True
```